# Creating Rule to Check for Validity of SSN string and Binding to Column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table Person with a column SSN . I want to use a rule
to make sure the SSN items entered are syntactically- correct, i.e.,
they consist of strings of the form xxx-xx-xxxx where each x is a
positive integer in {0,1,2,..,9}

```
Person  ( PersonID Primary Key NOT NULL, 
 Int, SSN  VarChar(11), FName  Char(50), LName Char(50))
```

and ultimately bind the rule

```
CREATE Rule SSN Validation
AS 
@Variable LIKE  ‘[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]‘
```

I then bind it:

```
Exec Sp_bindrule
```

Am I on the right track?

I also wanted to exclude a few values from the list. I don't have an idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I first want you to know that rules are deprecated with SQL Server.
A better solution would be to have a function to test the value or a stored procedure that handles the insert and also tests the value.

A function could look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IsValidSSN
(
    @value VARCHAR(11)
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result BIT;
    IF (@value LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
        SET @result = 1;
    ELSE
        SET @result = 0;

    RETURN @result;
END;

GO
```

To test it:

```
DECLARE @ssn VARCHAR(11) = '012-34-5678'

SELECT dbo.IsValidSSN(@ssn)

SELECT @ssn = 'A12-34-5678'

SELECT dbo.IsValidSSN(@ssn)
```

After adding the function you can add a CHECK constraint for that column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Person ADD CONSTRAINT ssnCheck CHECK (dbo.IsValidSSN(SSN) = 1)
```

To test it

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Person
(
    PersonID,
    SSN,
    FName,
    LName
)
VALUES
(   1,  -- PersonID - int
    '111-22-3333', -- SSN - varchar(11)
    'A', -- FName - char(50)
    'B'  -- LName - char(50)
    )

INSERT INTO dbo.Person
(
    PersonID,
    SSN,
    FName,
    LName
)
VALUES
(   2,  -- PersonID - int
    'Z11-22-3333', -- SSN - varchar(11)
    'AA', -- FName - char(50)
    'BB'  -- LName - char(50)
    )
```

The result:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 22
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "ssnCheck". The conflict occurred in database "DB1", table "dbo.Person", column 'SSN'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

If you're still willing to go with rules, this what it would look something like:

```
CREATE RULE SSN_Validation
AS
@Variable LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]';
GO

EXEC sys.sp_bindrule @rulename = N'SSN', @objname = N'dbo.Person.SSN';
```

Comment: While it's tempting to encapsulate this in a scalar valued function, those cause lots of problems around [parallelism](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/12/23/forcing-a-parallel-query-execution-plan.aspx) that get worse when you use them in [computed columns](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/01/another-reason-why-scalar-functions-in-computed-columns-is-a-bad-idea/) and [check constraints](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/04/another-hidden-parallelism-killer-scalar-udfs-check-constraints/).